# Force HttpClient or WebRequest to use TLS 1.0 for negative test

Tags: .net, https, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient, .net-security

With the [trend to disable TLS 1.0](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106310/should-i-disable-tls-1-0-on-my-servers) at server side, I need a negative test in C#. This should be a single test method among many others that will test other features, and we have parallel tests. Therefore, [the global setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=netframework-4.7#System_Net_ServicePointManager_SecurityProtocol) at ServicePointManager does not work for me.

Is there a way to force TLS 1.0 just for the connection of a single request?

Perhaps there is a low-level solution that involves creating a [SslStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netframework-4.7) or [NegotiateStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.negotiatestream?view=netframework-4.7)?